# Dynamically changing classes when liking comments?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to dynamically change the class of two div's and the number of likes. Everything seems to me as if they should be working but they don't. Here's the code I have this far:

```
function voteup(id){
  var v = parseInt($('#span_'+id).text());
  if ($('#up_'+id).hasClass('liked')){
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "voteSystem.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      $('#up_'+id).removeClass('liked');
        $('#span_'+id).text(v - 1);
      $('#vote_count_'+id).removeClass("chakraliked");
    }
    ajax.send("id="+id+"&n=n");
  } else {
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "voteSystem.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ($('#vote_count_'+id).hasClass("chakradisliked")){
        $('#vote_count_'+id).removeClass("chakradisliked");
        $('#up_'+id).removeClass('disliked');
        $('#vote_count_'+id).addClass("chakraliked");
        $('#down_'+id).addClass('liked');
        $('#span_'+id).text(v + 2);
      } else {
        $('#vote_count_'+id).addClass("chakraliked");
        $('#down_'+id).addClass('liked');
        $('#span_'+id).text(v + 1);
      }
    }
    ajax.send("id="+id+"&l=l");
  }
}
```

I can't really add the html as it's too much, but there's basically a like button (up_id) and a dislike button (down_id) and a span where the number of likes and the word "Chakra" is and the number is inside of a span called (span_id), but there's much more to it so I can't just show you the whole html as it's really big. Anyway, for some reason the jquery does work perfectly fine as far as the voting and running the php voteSystem is concerned, but I don't understand why the classes and the number doesn't change correctly...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by separating my last ajax function into two separate ajax functions for each case that was inside the first one. The finished jquery/ajax script looks like this

```
function voteup(id){
  var v = parseInt($('#span_'+id).text());
  if ($('#up_'+id).hasClass('liked')){
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "voteSystem.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      $('#up_'+id).removeClass('liked');
      $('#vote_count_'+id).removeClass("chakraliked");
      $('#span_'+id).text(v - 1);
    }
    ajax.send("id="+id+"&n=n");
  } else if ($('#down_'+id).hasClass('disliked')){
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "voteSystem.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      $('#down_'+id).removeClass('disliked');
      $('#vote_count_'+id).removeClass("chakradisliked");
      $('#up_'+id).addClass('liked');
      $('#vote_count_'+id).addClass("chakraliked");
      $('#span_'+id).text(v + 2);
    }
    ajax.send("id="+id+"&l=l");
  } else {
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "voteSystem.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      $('#up_'+id).addClass('liked');
      $('#vote_count_'+id).addClass("chakraliked");
      $('#span_'+id).text(v + 1);
    }
    ajax.send("id="+id+"&l=l");
  }
}
```